# The satisfaction I GOT from vs The satisfaction I FELT from....which is correct?

Tags: word-difference

Which of these two sentences is correct, and why?

The satisfaction I got from helping others instigated my interest in the world of medicine.

The satisfaction I felt from helping others instigated my interest in the world of medicine.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think one is right and one is wrong?

You can **get** (="obtain") satisfaction from something, and you can **feel** satisfaction from something.

Having said that, I would be more inclined to say "feel satisfaction **at** something" rather than **from** something, but I wouldn't say "from" is wrong.

Comment: If they both are right, how do I know which to use? What is the difference between getting satisfaction vs feeling satisfaction?

Comment: @Kayla It's the same difference as that between ***getting*** *food* and ***eating*** *food*. What is the *specific* thing you are trying to describe? The action of obtaining satisfaction or the sensation of experiencing it? Note that it's possible to describe both at the same time—even though it's a bit more long-winded: *The **feeling of satisfaction I got** from . . .* But, really, the meanings are so close that it comes down to whichever sounds better to you.

Answer (score 1):

In the example given, there is little or no difference of meaning, and which to use is purely a matter of style. The version with "felt" emphasized the emotions of the person feeling satisfaction, while the other version treats it as more of an objective fact. That is a question of what the speaker or author wants to convey. It is also a rather subtle difference.